# mysql php optimization with foreign key alphabetical order

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I've got 2 tables:

```
users:
| id | name | email | pass |

requests:
| id | userId | date | text |
```

`requests.userId` is foreign key to `users.id`. Now With php I have the query that looks more or less like this:

```
select u.name,r.date,r.text from requests r 
JOIN users u ON u.id=r.userId 
order by u.name ASC
```

I just want to have them sorted alphabetically by user name. It works really slow, I was reading about indexes but found no such issue. Have anybody any ideas on that, how could I speed it up? Thanks.

edit:
specially for this I made database with over 5000 users and 2000000 requests so I can see when it slows. When it sorts by integers or date it's couple of times faster.

Comment: Well do you have an index on the `name` column …?

Comment: I can't add it to name column. I've been searching for what's required to make an index and nothing went up.

Comment: What does _you can’t_ actually mean? How to add an index is described in the manual, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
 select u.name,r.date,r.text from requests r,users u where u.id=r.userId order by u.name ASC
```

Comment: This doesn't really seem like it would work but you should clarify your answer nevertheless, don't just say "Try it"

Comment: unfortunately, didn't speed at all. Thanks for any idea anyway.